# Eliminate letters of a list

Tags: list, haskell, split

I'm stuck in one exercise where i need to   letters of a list.
Example :

```
[A,23,XY,4] the resultant list should be [23,4]
```

I was thinking on using recursion, but how do i do the verification, if is a letter or no.
I read the splitOn, but i had the same problem, what i write to verificate?

```
splitOn (...) [A,4,d,1]
(...) -> what i put here?
```

For example in Java, exits the method isDigit, exist any method like this in haskell?

Comment: `Data.Char` contains many character classification functions, see [this](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Char+-%3E+Bool)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of your list is wrong.

```
[A,23,XY,4]
```

This doesn't mean anything in Haskell....  There are at least two problems with this.

1. keywords that start with a capital letter are reserver in Haskell for types (like `Int` or `String`).
2. Lists of mixed types aren't allowed.

This being said, I am going to guess from your question that you intended to use a list of `Char`s.

```
['A', '2', 'X', '4']
```

(note- in Haskell, a list of `Char`s is just a string, so this can also be written as "A2X4")

If this is the case, you can remove the alphabetic chars using a few standard functions.

```
filter (not . isAlpha) ['A', '2', 'X', '4']
```

---

On the other hand, if you might also need to filter a list of Strings.

```
["A", "23", "XY", "4"]
```

This can be done similarly

```
filter (not . all isAlpha) ["A", "23", "XY", "4"]
```

to filter out any string that is all alphabetic characters, or

```
filter (not . any isAlpha) ["A", "23", "XY", "4"]
```

to filter out any string that contains any alphabetic character.

Note, you will need to import `Data.Char` to make these snippets work.